# Not able to generate a static second page - fop

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

I am trying to generate a PDF using FOP.

My requirement-

Page 1 - Header and content

Page 2 - Static page for terms

Page 3 - Overflow from page 1

However, when there is no overflow from page 1, the page 2 is not getting generated. I want the second page to be generated even if there is no overflow from page 1. And, I have a different layout for page 2.

Below is the fo file with layout set-

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions"
         xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <!-- layout for the first page -->
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first"
                               th:attr="page-width=${dimensions.width} + 'in',page-height=${dimensions.height} + 'in',margin-right=${rightMargin} + 'in',margin-left=${leftMargin} + 'in'"
                               margin-top="0pt" margin-bottom="1in">
            <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" margin-top="3.3in" margin-bottom="0.375in"/>
            <fo:region-before region-name="stmt-header" margin-top="0.5in"/>
            <fo:region-after region-name="stmt-footer"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>

        <!-- layout for the other pages -->
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="rest"
                               th:attr="page-width=${dimensions.width} + 'in',page-height=${dimensions.height} + 'in',margin-right=${rightMargin} + 'in',margin-left=${leftMargin} + 'in'"
                               margin-top="0pt" margin-bottom="1in">
            <fo:region-body margin-bottom="0.375in" margin-top="1in"/>
            <fo:region-before region-name="stmt-header-1" margin-top="0.5in"/>
            <fo:region-after region-name="stmt-footer"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>

        <!-- layout for the other pages -->
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="terms"
                               th:attr="page-width=${dimensions.width} + 'in',page-height=${dimensions.height} + 'in',margin-right=${rightMargin} + 'in',margin-left=${leftMargin} + 'in'"
                               margin-top="0pt" margin-bottom="1in">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="10in" margin-bottom="0.1in"/>
            <fo:region-before region-name="stmt-terms" margin-top="0.5in"/>
            <fo:region-after region-name="stmt-footer-1"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>

        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="Statement">
            <!--<fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>-->
                <!--<fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="first" page-position="first"/>-->
                <!--<fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="terms" page-position="only"/>-->
                <!--<fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="rest" page-position="rest"/>-->
            <!--</fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>-->
            <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="first"/>
            <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="terms"/>
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="rest" page-position="rest"/>
            </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>

    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <!-- end: defines page layout -->

    <!-- actual layout -->
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="Statement" id="stmt">

        <fo:static-content flow-name="stmt-header">
            <th:block th:include="header-logo :: header-logo"/>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:static-content flow-name="stmt-header-1">
            <th:block th:include="header-logo :: header-logo-1"/>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:static-content th:with="footer_margin_left=1.7" flow-name="stmt-footer">
            <th:block th:include="footer"/>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:static-content th:with="footer_margin_left=0" flow-name="stmt-footer-1">
            <th:block th:include="footer"/>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:static-content flow-name="stmt-terms">
            <th:block th:include="stmt_terms :: stmt-terms"/>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <th:block th:include="${templateLayoutContent} :: stmt-body"/>
        </fo:flow>



    </fo:page-sequence>

</fo:root>
```

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this: [force-page-count="even"](https://www.data2type.de/xml-xslt-xslfo/xsl-fo/xslfo-referenz/attribute/force-page-count/)
This assures that your page-sequence will always have even pages. In fact there has to be a second page then. If there is no content on the page, you can specify the used page-master and static content by the [blank-or-not-blank](https://www.data2type.de/xml-xslt-xslfo/xsl-fo/xslfo-referenz/attribute/blank-or-not-blank/) attribute of the conditional-page-master.

Comment: Force-page-count="even" makes sure that second page is always there. But, how do i ensure that when there is an overflow (from 1st onto 3rd page) there should be no 4th page (which would be blank)

Comment: There are two not perfect solutions I can offer you. That one above is the first. The second is to add a fo:block with the attribute break-after="even-page". Both solution have the same problem as you noticed already. I do not think that you can fix that, since xsl is not page aware and you can not define a minimum of pages.

Comment: How static is the static page? Can it be a PDF  or image?

Comment: You can read up on the area tree and format to it and then reorder pages

Comment: The static page (page 2) has static text. The content from first page should overflow to the third page. The second page always has static content.
Yes it is a PDF.